# Sharepoint 2010 | Authentication & Authorization

Tags: .net, authentication, sharepoint, windows-authentication, httpmodule

I have a windows application based on .NET framework 2.0. It uses windows authentication. 
It also maintains the user details like user-id, valid from date, valid to date, active/inactive flag in its database(oracle). These details are also validated during log in process along with authenticating the user against windows credentials.

From this application, few screens are identified to migrate them as share-point 2010 application. After migration,

- Instead of launching windows forms, these web screens from share-point portal would be launched from the current Windows applications.
- The web screens would also be launched from one another intranet share-point portal.

User base for both windows application and intranet portal are same.

The authentication & authorization requirement for these newly migrated web-screen is to behave in the same way how their counter-part windows forms are behaving. In the existing windows application & intranet share-point application (from where the newly migrated web screens would be launched), user might be the current windows logged-in user or they can sign-in as different windows user.

There is a WCF service that exposes the user details – active flag, validity dates.

To validate whether the user has access to these web screens , apart from using OOTB share-point windows authentication , we would also need a customization here.

Would implementation of custom HTTPModule that would call to the WCF service be a good option here? Please suggest any other approach that would be a better solution here.

Edit:

If I have to specify in short, on top of windows authentication, there needed a customized user validation. There is a WCF service already in place that provides the valid user/invalid user response for a given user id. Now the question here is where can i plug-in this WCF call that does the custom validation?

Comment: "To validate whether the user has access to these web screens , apart from using OOTB share-point windows authentication , we would also need a customization here." Please elaborate on this point. Why do you need additional customization here? SharePoint has strong support for authorization and authentication. You can configure pages to be accessible only certain sharepoint groups/security group. I don't think you need the complexity of HTTPModule at all

Comment: Each user is configured with valid from and to dates and active/inactive flag. The application has to validate the user with these details also along with windows authentication.So there should be validation on top of windows authentication. So need the customization here. Can you please provide the details how to configures the page level security